# Fix "This sign in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempts or repeated shutdowns"

Tags: windows, login, windows-11, password-recovery, pin

I have a problem with sign-in to windows 11 account using PIN, when i try there's always prompt with "Please type code "A1B2C3" and after that i type my PIN, but always i got back "This sign-in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempt or repeated shutdowns. Use a different sign-in option, or keep your device powered on for at least 2 hours ad then try again." There is no "I forgot my PIN" and there is not option of changing type of sign-in and there's only one account and i don't even know if it's normal of admin account >.< I tried to wait 2 hours with device powered on for 2 hours but nothing changed, I also tried boot windows in safe mode with network, but it also did't work. I also tired booting up hirensbootcd and change password using this instruction https://www.hirensbootcd.org/howtos/ it also did't work. Do you know any way to reset this PIN ? Or at least this prompt ""This sign-in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempt or repeated shutdowns. Use a different  ...  " If it's important i have access to microsoft account with bitlocker key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I take it as you are unable to sign into your local account attached to your Microsoft Account?

Comment: You need to have another account to which you know how to login. Failing that, don't you get any other option or anything to click on the login screen?

Comment: Use the alphanumeric code and then use Forgot PIN to make a new PIN